# Xamarin.Forms: Custom renderer for displaying disclosure indicator on UITableViewCell

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to show a disclosure indicator on my table view cell for iOS. I found [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18131/listview-cell-arrow-disclosure-indicator) and a custom renderer has been proposed. I tried this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (EmployeeCell), typeof (EmployeeCellRenderer))]

namespace HelloXamarinFormsWorld.iOS
{
    public class EmployeeCellRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (Cell item, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell (item, tv);

            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

This file is called `EmployeeCellRenderer` and can be found in the root directory of the iOS solution. Such a custom renderer can be also found [here](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Todo/Todo.iOS/TodoItemCellRenderer.cs).

If I want to compile this I get

> Error CS0115: `HelloXamarinFormsWorld.iOS.EmployeeCellRenderer.GetCell(Xamarin.Forms.Cell, UIKit.UITableView)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (HelloXamarinFormsWorld.iOS)

These are my includes:

```
using System;
using HelloXamarinFormsWorld;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using HelloXamarinFormsWorld.iOS;
using UIKit;
```

How can I add a disclosure indicator to my table view cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the `GetCell()` method changed. It is now:

```
public override UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
{
    return base.GetCell (item, reusableCell, tv);
}
```

The reason for the change is the support for reusing cells.

The easiest way to figure these things out is to simply type `override` in your code file, followed by a blank (space). Intellisense will then show all overridable methods of the base class(es).

Comment: Bonus question: Do you know how to deal with the indentation when using a disclosure indicator?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: You better make it a separate question, since it is not directly related.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723991/xamarin-forms-remove-indentation-when-using-a-disclosure-button) you go. Thanks!