# Xamarin.Forms: Remove indentation when using a disclosure button

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to use a disclosure button on my table view cell. Therefore I use this custom renderer:

```
using HelloXamarinFormsWorld;
using HelloXamarinFormsWorld.iOS;
using UIKit;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using System.Drawing;
using ObjCRuntime;

/* Example of using a custom renderer to get the > disclosure indicator to appear */
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (EmployeeCell), typeof (EmployeeCellRenderer))]

namespace HelloXamarinFormsWorld.iOS
{
    public class EmployeeCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell (item, reusableCell, tv);

            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

//          // Remove seperator inset
//          if (cell.RespondsToSelector (new Selector ("setSeparatorInset:"))) {
//              cell.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
//          }
//          // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
//          if (cell.RespondsToSelector (new Selector ("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:"))) {
//              cell.PreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false;
//          }
//          // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
//          if (cell.RespondsToSelector (new Selector ("setLayoutMargins:"))) {
//              cell.LayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
//          }

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

If I set the disclosure indicator I get the following screen:
[image: with disclosure indicator]

Normally it does look like the following
[image: without disclosure indicator]

I tried to play with the inset, but that has to be in `WillDisplay` and also the indentation is not removed. In [this thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18131/listview-cell-arrow-disclosure-indicator#latest) *rmarinho* states

> you can fix by setting the UIEdgeInsets i think , i use the Padding property on [ExtendedViewCell](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/ExtendedViewCell/ExtendedViewCellRenderer.cs) for this.

but I don't know where I should do this. Or how do I fix the indentation?

**Edit:**

Using `cell.SeparatorInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0,0,0,0);` didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be a bug in `Xamarin.Forms`.

After looking into the decompiled code, I have found that the default `ViewCellRenderer` tries to center itself by calculating the content view of the cell, which is not correct as it didn't consider the size of `DisclosureIndicator`.

So, **the workaround** is to insert an indicator manually (*that's what ExtendedViewCell did*) and do not use the default disclosure indicator.

Comment: Do you mean to use a simple image?